# Where did I go wrong in evaluating $\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\cos \theta)^{2n} d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Using Complex Analysis methods, evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\cos \theta)^{2n}d\theta$$
where $n$ is a positive integer.

This is what I did:
$$\cos\theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}$$
So
$$I_{n} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left( \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}\right)^{2n}d\theta$$

Let the contour $C$ be the unit circle.
$z = e^{i\theta}$
$dz = ie^{i\theta}d\theta = iz d\theta$

So
$$
I_n = -i\int_C\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)^{2n}\frac{1}{z}\ dz\\ = -\frac{i}{4^n}\int_C \left(\frac{z^2+1}{z}\right)^{2n}\frac{1}{z}\ dz \\ = -\frac{i}{4^n}\int_C\frac{(z^2+1)^{2n}}{z^{2n+1}} \ dz
$$
The integrand hasa pole of order $2n+1$ at $z=0$.
Since the integrand is its own laurent series centred at $z=0$,
then 
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,0) = \begin{cases}-i \quad \text{n=0},\\0 \quad \  \ \ \text{else.}\end{cases}$$

Hence, 
$$I_n = \begin{cases}2\pi \qquad \text{n=0},\\ 0 \qquad \text{else.}\end{cases}
$$

However, this is incorrect as I evaluate different powers of $\cos$ and it seems to be non-zero. Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the binomial theorem to find the true coefficients of the Laurent series. The coefficient that is relevant for the integral is the central one, $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: oh rookie mistake... so it simplifies the integral to $$I_n = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n}n?$$

Comment: Yes. You do not really need the residue calculus for that as the expansion of the complex form of the cosine already allows for an easy integration.